# Pandas find data with loc function having special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I'm trying to find data in my dataframe which doesn't include this string []
In my dataset I have in column tags these values:

[image]

I'm using following code but it doesn't work as I expect

```
conversion_rate = deals.loc[(deals["businessCaseType_value"] =='Sale LiteScope') & (deals["tags"] != "[]]")
```

I'm usidng similar code elsewhere in project and it works just fine

```
hit_rate = len(deals.loc[(deals["businessCaseType_value"]=='Sale LiteScope') & (deals["status"]=='E_WIN')].index)
```

Is this due to special characters []?

Comment: Instead of `(deals["tags"] != "[]]")` did you mean `(deals["tags"] != "[]")`? Also, you're sure that 'tags' is a column of strings not lists?

Comment: You are right column tags is list :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have added

```
deals.tags =deals.tags.apply(lambda y: np.nan if len(y)==0 else y)
```

to convert all empty strings to NaN and then update my code

```
conversion_rate = deals.loc[(deals["businessCaseType_value"] =='Sale LiteScope') & deals["tags"].notnull()]
```

Thanks a lot